# My SOAP Web client gives a nullpointer execption when attempting to run it

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

IDE: Eclipse Luna SR2
Java version: 8 update 45
Server: Apache Tomcat 8.0.21

I'm creating a Dynamic Web Application in Eclipse and Associated REST and SOAP web services for a uni assignment. My question is specifically regarding the client for the web service. The client will ask the user to pick from a series of options displayed in the console by typing the option number into the console. It will then act based upon the option selected. When I try the first option, "view all articles", it gives me a null pointer exception. Full details, including classes and console output are below.

Console output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at uts.assignment2.soap.client.NewsClient.main(NewsClient.java:24)
```

NewsClient.java:

```
package uts.assignment2.soap.client;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;
import au.edu.uts.www._31284.wsd_news.*;

public class NewsClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ServiceException,
            RemoteException {
        NewsSOAPServiceLocator locator = new NewsSOAPServiceLocator();
        NewsSOAP service = locator.getNewsSOAPPort();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (;;) {
            System.out.println("Select an option:");
            System.out.println("1: view all articles");
            System.out.println("2: delete an article");
            System.out.println("3: exit");
            System.out.print("enter choice: ");
            int option = scanner.nextInt();
            switch (option) {
            case 1:
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < service.getArticles().length; i++) {
                        Article article = service.getArticle(i);
                        System.out.println(article);
                        System.out.println();
                        //System.out.println(article.getAuthor());
                        //System.out.println();
                        //System.out.println(article.getPublishedDate());
                        //System.out.println();
                        //System.out.println(article.getShortText());
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;
            case 2:
                System.out
                        .print("Enter the ID of the article you wish to delete: ");
                int id = scanner.nextInt();
                service.deleteArticle(id);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NewsSOAP.java (the service itself - the client proxies are auto-generated form the wsdl by JAX-WS):

```
package uts.assignment2.soap;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import uts.assignment2.*;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;

@WebService(targetNamespace="http://client.soap.assignment2.uts")
public class NewsSOAP {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext context;

    private NewsApplication getNewsApp() throws JAXBException, IOException {
        ServletContext application = (ServletContext) context.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
        synchronized (application) {
            NewsApplication newsApp = (NewsApplication) application.getAttribute("newsApp");
            if (newsApp == null) {
                newsApp = new NewsApplication();
                newsApp.setFilePath(application.getRealPath("WEB-INF/news.xml"));
                application.setAttribute("newsApp", newsApp);
            }
            return newsApp;
        }
    }

    @WebMethod
    public News getArticles() {
        News news = null;
        try {
            news = getNewsApp().getArticles();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return news;
    }

    @WebMethod
    public Article getArticle(int id) {
        Article article = null;
        try {
            article = getNewsApp().getArticles().getArticle(id);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return article;
    }

    @WebMethod
    public void deleteArticle(int id) {
        try {
            getNewsApp().getArticles().removeArticle(getNewsApp().getArticles().getArticle(id));
            getNewsApp().updateXML();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("The ID entered does not match an article in our records. Please enter a valid ID: ");
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is that I cannot figure out where the client is falling down. I can see which line the NullPointerException points to, but I cannot figure out where it falls down. Any help is appreciated. If any extra information is required, please ask and I will endeavour to provide it. Thank you.

Comment: Which line *does* it point to? Which line is line 24 of NewsClient.java?

Comment: @TimoSta: Line 24 is where the "for" loop begins in the try block: for (int i = 0; i < service.getArticles().length; i++). A little more info that may be relevant: The SOAP service access a Java Bean, which in turn loads the objects from an XML file using JAXB.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment in below code.

NewsSOAP.java

```
 @WebMethod
    public News getArticles() {
        News news = null;
        try {
            news = getNewsApp().getArticles();     //Recursive call of getArticles() within it's own method. Which in turn setting news=null, causing null pointer exception at service.getArticles().length in for loop.
        }
```

NewsClient.java:

```
for (int i = 0; i < service.getArticles().length; i++)
```